# Where to check logs for flink streaming job?

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

I have a flink streaming job continuously running on YARN. I am not able to see any application logs for running job . I only get logs when running as standalone java program.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no direct way to check logs when running on YARN.

I have found an alternative . I have added Flink Rolling Sink to my streaming job which is writing logs to hdfs location with YYYY-mm-dd--HH
format.

On top of that creating hive table to query on logs.

Answer (score 0):

The output of your Flink job will be written to the standard output on the TaskManagers.

**EDIT** : when the job is finished : On YARN, you might access that output by retrieving all logs using the aggregated YARN logs (`yarn logs -applicationId <appid>`) if you have enabled it.

A quick and dirty solution is to send your output in a sink socket for instance.

Comment: For the YARN logs you're right, for the standard output or the sink socket it works.